# Mouse hold on a custom made div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I'm working on `The Odin Project - Etch-A-Sketch` project.

I'm trying to give the user the ability to draw grey pixels while they have their mouse held down. I couldn't find a `mousehold` event. What I have found is that I must do this on my own. In my `Javascript` I have an event listener for mousedown that turns on a boolean. If that boolean is on AND the user crosses over a `pixel div` that `pixel` turns grey.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes the `mouseup` listener doesn't trigger to turn my boolean off. It instead will drag the pixels as though I'm trying to drag the picture off the site. That is when the `mouseup` doesn't complete its job. I can't seem to figure out when this bug will occur. I can draw slowly and still get the bug. I can do it quickly and still get the bug. There is no repeatable that I have found.

Is there a better way to "draw" on these pixels? Am I using the `mouseup` and `mousedown` events correctly? Is there another event I should be using?

[image: Picture of the problem]

The `HTML` is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left-btn-group">
        <!-- 3 buttons for pixel size -->
        <button id="low">Low Resolution</button>
        <button id="medium">Medium Resolution</button>
        <button id="High">High Resolution</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear Canvas</button>
        <button id="color">Color Picker</button>
        <!-- Buttons to add -->
    </div>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
    <div id="right-btn-group"></div>
</body>
```

The `Javascript` is where most of the work is done:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

// get size of canvas
let canvasWidth = canvas.clientWidth;
let canvasHeight = canvas.clientHeight;

const LOW_RES = 16;
const MID_RES = 32;
const HIGH_RES = 64;
create_pixels(MID_RES);

//redo the canvas if the user changes the resolution
const lowResButton = document.getElementById("low");
lowResButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    deletePixels();
    create_pixels(LOW_RES);
})
const midResButton = document.getElementById("medium");
midResButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    deletePixels();
    create_pixels(MID_RES);
})
const highResButton = document.getElementById("High");
highResButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    deletePixels();
    create_pixels(HIGH_RES);
})

const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");
clearButton.addEventListener("click", function (){
    let pixels = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("pixel"));
    pixels.forEach(e => {
        e.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
})

function deletePixels(){
    let pixels = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("pixel"));
    pixels.forEach(element => {
        element.remove();
    });
}

function create_pixels(res) {
    let numberOfVerticalPixels = res;
    // make the pixels square
    // get the height of the pixels
    let pixelHeight = Math.floor(canvasHeight / res);
    let numberOfHorizontalPixels = Math.floor(canvasWidth / pixelHeight);
    let pixelWidth = pixelHeight;

    // calculate number of pixels needed to fill the canvas 
    let numberOfPixels = numberOfHorizontalPixels * numberOfVerticalPixels;
    let newCanvasWidth = numberOfHorizontalPixels * pixelWidth;
    canvas.style.width = newCanvasWidth + "px";
    let newCanvasHeight = numberOfVerticalPixels * pixelHeight;
    canvas.style.height = newCanvasHeight + "px";

    let stringStyle = "width:" + pixelWidth + "px; height: " + pixelHeight + "px;";
    // add them to canvas
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPixels; i++) {
        const pixel = document.createElement("div");
        pixel.classList.add("pixel")
        pixel.setAttribute("style", stringStyle);
        pixel.addEventListener("mouseover", changeColor);
        canvas.appendChild(pixel);
    }
}

// Program the hold and color feature
// Get mousedown
// get location of mouse
// get mouseup
let down = false;
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
function mousedown(){
    down = true;
    console.log("true");
}
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
function mouseup(){
    down = false;
    console.log("false");
}

function changeColor(e){
    if (down){
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    }
}
```

The `CSS` just in case that is causing an issue:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;    
    min-height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

#left-btn-group,
#right-btn-group{
    flex-basis: 20%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#left-btn-group button{
    display: block;
    width: 75%;
}

#canvas {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 50px solid red;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#canvas-border {
    width: 99%;
    height: 99%;
}
```

Comment: You need to prevent the default action for mousedown, eg `event.preventDefault()` also might want to put the mouseup event on the document that way if you mouse out of the canvas and then let up it doesnt continue to draw

Comment: Ohhh, that sounds like it will work great. Where do I put `event.preventDefault()`? I know about the exiting the canvas bug I have just been bashing my head against a wall with this bug first.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Found it. Thanks. Can you add this as an answer so I can give you credit?